# detect the HOST domain name in django models

Tags: django, django-models, django-urls

In my model, I want to use the domain name (HOST) I'm using in my views.
In views that'd be doable, thanks to the "request" object. But how do I do 
this models methods? Which don't use "HttpRequest" objects?

Now I'm setting a global value HOST in settings.py and using it, but that's 
ugly.

Also, I don't really want to manage "Sites" (the Sites app) — Is there a way, 
I can grab the "by default" Site Host name?

Thanks a lot for your help! (and sorry for my poor English)

Answer (score 2):

If you're calling the model method from a view, you could add a parameter for the request to the model method and include it when you call it from the view.  E.g.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    def MyMethod(self, request):
        # Do whatever with request here

def MyView(request):
    mm = MyModel()
    mm.MyMethod(request)
```

Comment: I'm officially stupid! Thanks, Adam! :) So I just need to use request.META['SERVER_NAME'] in that method, right? :) Again, Thanks a lot!

Comment: That looks like the one you'd need.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use " request.get_host() " method of HttpRequest to get the Domain name of the site this will return the originating host of the request using information from the HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST and HTTP_HOST headers and if dont provide value, The method will use the combination of SERVER_NAME and SERVER_PORT .

Answer (score 1):

If the `request` object is unavailable, the best way is to use the [Django Sites framework](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/#getting-the-current-domain-for-full-urls), I think.  This requires having correctly set the `site.domain` (and `site.name`, if you want) beforehand.  `.get_current` is set according to your `django.conf.settings.SITE_ID`.

```
>>> from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
>>> obj = MyModel.objects.get(id=3)
>>> obj.get_absolute_url()
'/mymodel/objects/3/'
>>> Site.objects.get_current().domain
'example.com'
>>> 'http://%s%s' % (Site.objects.get_current().domain, obj.get_absolute_url())
'http://example.com/mymodel/objects/3/'
```