# How do I detect the current domain name in django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates

I want to design my web application to serve two different front-end templates depending on what domain the user enter my django application.

So, if the user enter aaa.com, it would serve front-end from app AAA_USA, but if the user enter from aaa.co.my, it would serve front-end from app AAA_MY.

What is the best way to do this? I was thinking of "detecting the current domain name" and then simply add an if-else statements in the View functions.

These two domains will be pointing to the same Nameservers that contains my Django app.

Comment: Use  {{ request.get_host }}

Comment: thank you, but is there anyway to do it without request object? because i may also need to use it outside of view functions (that contains the request argument)

Comment: check this: Site.objects.get_current().domain https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/sites/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [detect the HOST domain name in django models](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400500/detect-the-host-domain-name-in-django-models)

Comment: Is there a way to do it without using the Site package? if no, thanks, i will try it and see if it's doable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way i did it is basically using the middleware (using session and detect the HTTP_HOST.

```
class SimpleMiddleware(object):
def __init__(self, get_response):
    self.get_response = get_response
    # One-time configuration and initialization.

def __call__(self, request):
    # Code to be executed for each request before the view (and later middleware) are called.

    # sets to show Taiwan or Indo version
    # sets the timezone too
    http_host = request.META['HTTP_HOST']
    if(http_host == 'http://www.xxx.tw'):
        request.session['web_to_show'] = settings.TAIWAN
        request.session['timezone_to_use'] = settings.TAIWAN_TIMEZONE
    else:
        request.session['web_to_show'] = settings.INDO
        request.session['timezone_to_use'] = settings.INDONESIA_TIMEZONE

    response = self.get_response(request)

    # Code to be executed for each request/response after the view is called.

    return response
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get a full url with **"build_absolute_uri()"**:

```py
def myview(request):
    request.build_absolute_uri()
    # http://localhost:8000/admin/store/product/
```

Then, this below can get the url without **"admin/store/product/"**:

```py
def myview(request):
    request.build_absolute_uri('/')
    # http://localhost:8000/
```

Then, this below can get the url without **"/admin/store/product/"**:

```py
def myview(request):
    request.build_absolute_uri('/')[:-1]
    # http://localhost:8000
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have access to the requests object, then you can use the [sites framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/sites/):

```
from django.contrib.sites.shortcuts import get_current_site
domain = get_current_site(None)
```

This will return the site the Django is configured for (using the value saved in the *django_site* table of your database. (See: [https://docs.djangoproject.com/.../sites/shortcuts/](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/_modules/django/contrib/sites/shortcuts/))

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
request.build_absolute_uri()
```

will retrive the full path:
es:

> http://localhost:8000/test/

Comment: is there anyway to do it without request object? because i may also need to use it outside of view functions (that contains the request argument)

Comment: without the request object is impossible.
2 ways
1) Pass as argument the request object in the other functions
2) in the first view save the value of the path in a cookie and read the cookie in the other functions